# Не проигрывается аудио в Chrome | Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Вот такая проблема в Chrome, как исправить?

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Html

```
<audio id="player" src="sound.mp3"></audio>
```

Js

```
document.getElementById('player').play();
```

Если нажать `ctrl+F5`, всё будет работать :) После обычного рефреша всё опять ломается.

Comment: Какое слово непонятно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: Да всё понятно, но это никак нельзя обойти? Страница сама рефрешится по таймеру.

Comment: Нельзя. Замените рефреш на ajax-запросы например